# Inline char to std::string conversion

Tags: c++, string, c++11, type-conversion

Is there a built-in method for constructing a `std::string` based on a given `char`?

The reason I ask this is because I want to make a function call directly within the `if` statement:

```
// Given function prototype
bool func(std::string s);

for(auto rit = s.rbegin(); rit != s.rend(); ++rit)
{
    if(func(*rit))
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
std::string(*rit)
static_cast<std::string>(*rit)
```

Comment: just write another function to handle char instead of string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The most concise way since C++11** is to construct via an initializer list:

```
func({*rit})
```

or if you need to explicitly specify the type (for a function template):

```
func(std::string{*rit})
```

---

**For pre-C++11**, it is the 2nd overload of the [`std::string`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
func(std::string(1, *rit))
```

Comment: In C++11 you can write `func({rit, rit+1});`, etc.